# unable to find Javascript option in Tools menu in pdf

Tags: pdf, javascript

I want to add javascript in PDF but I don't find Javascript option in Tools menu in pdf.

I have enabled all options from Edit -> Preferences -> Javascript

Comment: `PDF` is a document format, not a tool. Where exaclty are you looking for a `Tool` menu?

Comment: tool menu in pdf options

Comment: What program are you using? There are no "PDF Options" with a tools menu for that format. So you are likely using some program to view a PDF. What program are you using?

Comment: I am using Adobe Reader 9.0...and I want to add some custom controls in it using javascript.so i am finding a way to write javascript inside it.

Comment: [The Acrobat JavaScript Console (Your best friend for developing Acrobat JavaScript)](https://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/javascript_console)